# clearing the link id

Tags: php

if we have

```
$id = 39827-key1-key2-key3
```

and we want to show only the number or anything before (-)
then by using

```
$realid = array_shift(explode("-", $id));
```

we will get  `echo $realid; // 39827`

*Now my problem is as following !*

if we have `$id = key1/key2`
and i want any way that remove the whole part  `key1/` and gives me only `key2`

how can i do it?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense.  Please post some code that illustrates what you're currently doing.

Comment: Why doesn't make any sense ! Okay, if i have '$something = key1/key2' how to do anything that finally shows me only 'key2' !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, from your comment above, I'm assuming you want to do something like:

```
$id = "key1/key2";

$result = ???;

// Now $result=="$key2"
```

Why not just:

```
$parts = explode("/", $id);
$result = $parts[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`strstr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) function, which was created exactly for things like this:

```
$id = 'key1/key2';
$realid = strstr($id, '/', true);
```

Do note that you have to be running PHP 5.3 or newer for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

confusing question. my interpretation for `$rawId` containing the '/' char:

```
$rawId = 'key1/key2';
$realId = substr($rawId, 1 + strpos($rawId, '/')); // key2
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way:

```
$result = implode('', array_slice(explode('/', $id), 1, 1));
```